# Using this() in C# Constructors

Tags: c#, constructor

I have been trying to figure out if there are any differences between these constructors.  Assuming there is a Foo() constructor that takes no arguments, are all these constructors going to have the same result?

### Example 1

```
public Foo()
    : this()
{
     blah;
     blah;
     blah;
}
```

### Example 2

```
public Foo()
{
     this();
     blah;
     blah;
     blah;
}
```

### Example 3

```
public Foo()
{
     this = new Foo();
     blah;
     blah;
     blah;
}
```

Comment: +1 taught me something new with Example#3 n the fact that J S is always lurking

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- Example 1 is valid (assuming there is a parameterless constructor), and calls the parameterless constructor as part of initialization. See my [article on constructor chaining](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/constructors.html) for more details. EDIT: Note that since the OP's edit, it's infinitely recursive.
- Example 2 is never valid
- Example 3 is only valid when Foo is a struct, and doesn't do anything useful.

I would steer clear of assigning to `this` in structs. As you can see from the other answers, the very *possibility* of it is fairly rarely known (I only know because of some weird situation where it turned up in the spec). Where you've got it, it doesn't do any good - and in other places it's likely to be mutating the struct, which is *not* a good idea. Structs should always be immutable :)

EDIT: Just to make people go "meep!" a little - assigning to `this` isn't quite the same as just chaining to another constructor, as you can do it in methods too:

```
using System;

public struct Foo
{
    // Readonly, so must be immutable, right?
    public readonly string x;

    public Foo(string x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void EvilEvilEvil()
    {
        this = new Foo();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo("Test");
        Console.WriteLine(foo.x); // Prints "Test"
        foo.EvilEvilEvil();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.x); // Prints nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware 3 was legal, but you're right, it is.  I always accomplished the same thing by chaining the parameterless constructor.

Comment: I had always thought that : was used for inheritance - is there any inheritance happening in Example 1, or is this just an overloaded usage of the colon?

Comment: The colon just means something different in this context.  Constructor chaining on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx

Comment: That example is quite remarkable.  I'm very surprised that you can do such a thing.

Comment: @mquander: Yes, it's thoroughly evil, isn't it? Ick.

Comment: Is this still assuming there is a parameterless constructor for Foo?  If we defined a parameterless constructor that set x, wouldn't it behave as we would expect?

Comment: J S - you still the C# dude. But I wish I hadn't read that you can assign this to a new struct :)

Comment: @Tim: This is a struct - you can't write your own parameterless constructor (in C#, anyway - you can in IL).

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this thread. Isn't Example 1 effectively an infinitely recursive loop? I can see it working with `:base()` but not `:this()`.

Comment: @gnomed: When I answered it, the constructor had a parameter. I don't know why the OP changed it significantly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Aha, oh well. Good to know. Sorry to drag up old topics, and thanks for getting back to me. PS: Just noticed, the OP actually works in my office and is sitting about 5 desks away from me right now (same user picture as his work skype).... the internet is freaking me out.

Comment: @Jesse C. Slicer: Your edit made no sense... `Foo` *is* a type, so you don't declare the type *of* that. The original answer was made when there was a parameter called `bar`, with no specified type. It's fine to edit the answer because the question was changed, but please only edit it to something meaningful :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry about that. I must have picked the wrong week to stop sniffing glue.

Answer (score 11):

Examples 2 and 3 are not legal C#.

EDIT:  Jon points out accurately that 3 is legal when `Foo` is a `struct`.  Go check out his answer!

Comment: #3 is used as a copy constructor `struct Foo { int a; Foo(Foo other) { this=other; } }`

Answer (score 4):

No they will not because only the first constructor is actually legal.  The other two are illegal for various reasons.

**EDIT** Interesting, 3 is indeed legal when Foo is a struct.  But even in that case, it is a redundant assignment.