# Modifying a class instance from inside the class

Tags: c#, class, constructor, this

suppose i had a serializeable class such as

```
[Serializable]
    public class DatabaseViewModel:MVVM.ObservableObject 
    {
        //fields
        //properties

        public DatabaseViewModel()
        {
           //if a serialization file exists then deseralize and make this instance equal to it
           //else initialize fields
        }
    }
```

is it possible to do such thing from inside the class and not the calling scope?

in the calling scope i would just do

```
var dbvm = new DatabaseViewModel();
```

and then i want the constructor to decide if it should create a new object or load a serialized object.

inside my class i tried this

```
this = //my serialized object
```

if i wanted to do it from the calling scope i would just do

```
DatabaseViewModel dbvm = null;
if(File.Exists(".../DatabaseViewModel.bin")
dbvm = //deserialize .../DatabaseViewModel.bin
else
dbvm = new DatabaseViewModel();
```

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't normally put I/O in the constructor secondly you can't assign to this you'd need to assign to each field seperately

Comment: @RuneFS but what if i had too many fields?

Comment: @user1492051: Then you write many lines of code, or abstract it out to another method.

Comment: @Jon so better do it from the calling scope?

Comment: @user1492051 What you really want is [_factory pattern_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or [_builder pattern_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: how about Singleton or a Locator wich will be the entry point (initializer) of your VM ?

Comment: It actually sounds like you want to initialize to defaults, *or* initialize from file data. This is different from returning a *different, already constructed object*, like you would with a factory.

Comment: @crashmstr that class has multiple lists, and they get modified often after its serialized, in the next application run i want to load the last state of that objct, and i always have one instance of it

Comment: You are using the [Serializable] attribute, but this is not how that attribute is supposed to be used. Study the example at (the bottom of the page at) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't replace the `this` reference of an object. You can use a Factory/Builder, as was suggested.

However, a recently deserialized object has one difference to any other object: noone else has a reference to it. So while *this* isn't possible:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(MyClass arg)
    {
       this = arg;
    }
}
```

This is possible

```
class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(MyClass arg)
   {
      this.CopyFrom(arg);
   }

   void CopyFrom(MyClass m)
   {
      // Assign fields from m.
   }
}
```

Now if you replace the argument object to be copied, with what you need to find the deserialized data and deserialize internally:

```
class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(int id)
   {
      if (FileExistsOnDisk(id))
      {
         MyClass m = DeserializeFromFile(id);
         CopyFrom(m);
      }
      else
      {
          // Normal construction.
      }
   }
}
```

However, you *don't want to keep the persistence logic and IO in a constructor anyway* so you will get a much better design by simply making the choice between creation or deserialization of the object the responsibility of some other object, e.g. a factory/builder.

```
public class MyClassFactory
{
   public MyClass GetObj(int id)
   {
      if (FileExistsOnDisk(id))
         return DeserializeFromFile(id);
      else 
         return new MyClass(id);     
   }
}
```

> "if i wanted to do it from the calling scope i would just do"

And you do.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into factories: http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory. You cannot do this from constructor, as far as I know.

Also, check out this related post: [Using this() in C# Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001694/using-this-in-c-sharp-constructors).

Comment: You can (but probably shouldn't) do this from the constructor and your answers doesn't really provide an answer

Comment: You could do it by assigning to each field separately. It could also work if it was a struct.

Comment: Yes you could do a lot of things. However you are not choosing any of the possible options and thereby not providing a solution to the problem. There's nothing wrong with you comment, I just stated it's not giving any concrete advise for OP to follow but worse the actual information is on another site making this answer a short lived one because at some point (and often sooner than expected) the first link will die. THe second doesn't provide a solution