# using 'this' in a constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a class that I want to construct, by deserializing it from a network stream.

```
public Anfrage(byte[] dis)
    {
        XmlSerializer deser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Anfrage));
        Stream str = new MemoryStream();
        str.Write(dis, 0, dis.Length);
        this = (Anfrage)deser.Deserialize(str);
    }
```

The intention is that I just want to pass the byte[] and have a proper object, rather than using a method in another class.
Now, I know that I obviously cannot do **this =**.
I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001694/using-this-in-c-sharp-constructors) and currently am reading the article mentioned in it, but I am not sure wether I'm understanding it correctly.

Is my intention clear enough?

Is there a way to do what I want to get done here?

Thank you all.

Comment: You can assign to `this` in constructors for value types. It may not have the effect you expect, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot overwrite an object within the class itself by assigning to `this`.

You can for example create a method that *returns* a new instance:

```
public static Anfrage Create(byte[] dis)
{
    XmlSerializer deser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Anfrage));
    Stream str = new MemoryStream();
    str.Write(dis, 0, dis.Length);
    return (Anfrage)deser.Deserialize(str);
}
```

Then you can instantiate one like this:

```
var anfrage = Anfrage.Create(bytes);
```

Comment: So there is no way to create a constructor like  

`Anfrage whatev = new Anfrage(byteArrayFromSerialization)`?

Comment: Yeah you can, but then you'll have to do something like `temp = Deserialize()` and then copy all values from `temp` into `this`. You don't want that.

Answer (score 3):

Usually with this problem is dealt with a static non-constructor function returning the Object.

```
public static Anfrage Create(byte[] dis)
{
    XmlSerializer deser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Anfrage));
    Stream str = new MemoryStream();
    str.Write(dis, 0, dis.Length);
    return (Anfrage)deser.Deserialize(str);
}
```

if you want to have a new object and edit it, make the constructor private instead of public and acces it with you static construction function

Comment: Are you serious, or just a slow typer? ;-)

Comment: sorry, i clicked on Anwer and wrote the code... I always see, that my answer already is written by another guy, just after submitting it :(