# difference between writing this.propertyName or just propertyName

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm looking at an example writing a class and use the constructor and was wondering what the difference is of using the "this." or not.

So what is the differnce between:

```
public class PagedCountryList
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> CountriesToDisplay { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int PerPage { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public PagedCountryList(IEnumerable<Country> countries, int totalResult, int elementsPerPage, int pageNumber)
    {
        this.CountriesToDisplay = countries;
        this.Total = totalResult;
        this.PerPage = elementsPerPage;
        this.PageNumber = pageNumber;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
public class PagedCountryList
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> CountriesToDisplay { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int PerPage { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public PagedCountryList(IEnumerable<Country> countries, int totalResult, int elementsPerPage, int pageNumber)
    {
        CountriesToDisplay = countries;
        Total = totalResult;
        PerPage = elementsPerPage;
        PageNumber = pageNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: no difference. 'this.' is redundant in this case

Comment: `this` will be needed if your constructor takes parameters named the same as your properties.

Comment: might be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001694/using-this-in-c-sharp-constructors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no differences in your case but consider this example

```
public class PagedCountryList
{
    private IEnumerable<Country> countries { get; set; }
    public int totalResult { get; set; }
    public int elementsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }

    public PagedCountryList(IEnumerable<Country> countries, int totalResult, int elementsPerPage, int pageNumber)
    {
       //you cant write something like this (because it is ambiguous)
       //countries = countries;
        this.countries = countries;
        this.totalResult = totalResult;
        this.elementsPerPage = elementsPerPage;
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is no difference for your case. Here are the common uses of `this` depicted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

- To qualify members hidden by similar names
- To pass an object as a parameter to other methods
- To declare indexers

Answer (score 2):

As tom suggested, in this case "this" is redundant but that doesnt mean that you should'n use it.

Your member "public int Total" can be directly accessed with "this" or without. On the other hand if you have used Total as function parameter, you need to distinguish whether it is class member of function parameter with "this"

```
function SetTotal(int Total)
{
this.Total = Total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there is no difference. This is a reference to yourself.
It is usefull is some situations where in the same scope you have "duplicate named varibles".