# Updating this in Class that inherits from List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract class used for caching that implements as follows (simplified)

```
public abstract class DataCacheMember<T> : List<T>
{
    private List<T> _data;
    public List<T> Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (_data == null || _data.Count() < 1)
                _data = GetData();

            return _data;
        }
    }

    private string ApiEndPoint {get; set;}
    private Timer timer;

    private List<T> GetData()
    {
        //call api and get data
    }

    private void RefreshData()
    {
        _data = GetData();
    }

    protected DataCacheMember(string apiEndPoint)
    {
        ApiEndPoint = apiEndPoint;

        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            e => RefreshData(),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }
}
```

It allows for rapid creation of cached objects with a simple string for the api endpoint:

```
public class StateMap<Properties> : DataCacheMember<Properties>
{
    public StateMap(string apiEndPoint = "Property/GetProperties")
        : base(apiEndPoint)
    {}
}
```

The whole reason for inheriting from `List<T>` was to remove the need for the fields.

However, if I try to modify the constructor and refresh to:

```
private void RefreshData()
{
    this = GetData() as DataCacheMember<T>;
}

protected DataCacheMember(string apiEndPoint)
{
    this = GetData() as DataCacheMember<T>;
}
```

I get an error of `Cannot assign to <this> because it is Read Only`.

What's the proper way to resolve this? Do I just need to use `Clear()` and `AddRange()` to manage the object?

If I do that, I see that the first call to the object will return empty, because the object can return before the constructor finishes it's call.

Comment: Is it a list's responsibility to populate itself?

Comment: You should not inherit `List<T>`.

Comment: "The whole reason for inheriting from `List<T>` was to remove the need for the fields."  yet you have a field that stores a list - if your structure is not a list but rather _contains_ a list then model it that way - inheritance doesn't seem like the right design here.

Comment: Woah; why does it *have* a list when it *is* a list? That's just weird.

Comment: And why does it have fields if you didn't want to?

Comment: @MarcGravell The bent of the post is how to remove those very list properties, which I cannot do without assigning to the list

Comment: Looks like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem, perhaps go back and explain the issue you are having instead of this attempted solution.

Comment: @Wesley then D Stanley a viable suggestion with the `Clear` / `AddRange`, but again: fundamentally this seems very peculiar

Comment: @MarcGravell It does let me set the base class, but I can't modify the accessor to ensure `GetData()` is called before I try to return data. Therefore, I am going to remove the `List<T>` inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question you cannot assign `this` in a constructor or any other method.  You could add the items returned from `GetData()`:

```
private void RefreshData()
{
    this.Clear();
    this.AddRange(GetData());
}

protected DataCacheMember(string apiEndPoint)
{
    this.Clear();
    this.AddRange(GetData());
}
```

But *inheriting* form `List<T>` probably isn't the right design here.

Comment: Marking this correct because it technically works, but inheriting from `List<T>` is a bad idea. I cannot add null/empty checks in a way that overrides the parent accessor, and therefore cannot ensure `GetData()` has been called before I allow users to request the list.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Using this() in C# Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001694/using-this-in-c-sharp-constructors)

```
private void RefreshData()
{
    this = GetData() as DataCacheMember<T>;
}

protected DataCacheMember(string apiEndPoint)
{
    this = GetData() as DataCacheMember<T>;
}
```

These would only work in a struct and doesn't really do anything useful and is bad design.